# Help in usage of punctuation

Tags: punctuation

This sentence has been taken from Rudyard Kipling's "Lispeth".

> Whether Christianity improved Lispeth, or whether the gods of her own people would have done as much for her under any circumstances, I do not know; but she grew very lovely.

Another sentence from the same short story is

> Also, she possessed eyes that were wonderful; and, had she not been dressed in the abominable print-cloths affected by Missions, you would, meeting her on the hill side unexpectedly, have thought her the original Diana of the Romans going out to slay.

I would like to know why the punctuation ';' before 'but' in the first sentence and before 'and' in the second sentence is required. What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Do you know what a semicolon is?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Semicolon  Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/semicolon) by The Oxford Dictionaries, part of their [Punctuation Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/punctuation).

Comment: My purpose of asking this question was to know that if we remove the semicolon, the balance between the two clauses is not disturbed, In what way the meaning changes if we put a semicolon before a conjunction. So is it wrong to put a comma in place of semicolon in the above two sentences?